# TabItem is hovered with any of its control's hover event

Tags: wpf, events, controls, tabitem

When I hover a control like a textbox or a button inside a tab control, It hovers the the TabItem's header implementing its IsHover property style.
It also happens with the selection changed event of the combobox as it fires the selection changed event of the TabControl.

I knew that I can set the Eventargs for the hover event handler handled to true.

```
e.Handled=true;
```

I've many tab controls with its items including like hundreds of controls.
so i think it's a bad idea to handle each control's hover and selection changed events in all tab controls. 
I need to completely separate the Tabitem's events from its content's events.

this is how my Xaml is:

```
    <TabControl x:Name="tc_main" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,0,-10,0" SelectionChanged="tc_main_SelectionChanged">

        <TabItem Header="المحددات" x:Name="tci_id" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}"  Background="#FF892C7F" >
                        <Grid Width="1339.55" Style="{DynamicResource GridStyle1}">
                       <Button Content="Button" Margin="242,194,851.55,388" Click="Button_Click_1"/>



                            <TextBox Margin="234,103,859.55,509" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" FontSize="24" />
                            <Button Content="Button" Margin="590,194,503.55,388" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="590,103,516,509" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="233.55"/>
                            <Button Content="Button" Margin="234,474,859.55,108" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="234,383,872,229" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="233.55"/>
                            <Button Content="Button" Margin="590,474,503.55,108" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="590,383,516,229" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="233.55"/>
                            <Label x:Name="ss" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="112.775,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98"/>
                            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="234,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" IsEditable="True" Background="{x:Null}" >
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="ti1" >

                                </ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="ti2" >

                                </ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="ti3" >

                                </ComboBoxItem>

                            </ComboBox>
                            <Button Content="Button" Margin="495,103,762.05,450.5" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
                       </Grid>
        </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

the following event is being fired once I change the selection of the combobox..

```
 private void tc_main_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tc_main.SelectedItem == tci_id)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
```

Also the following Style of the TabItem is fired When I hover any control.
This is the style of the tabitem hover

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="27"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="-5"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE8E8E8"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="25,13,18,6"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,8,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="عنصر"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Adobe Arabic"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="mainBorder"
                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                     BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" 
                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                     Margin="0">
                    <Border x:Name="innerBorder" 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" 
                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" 
                    Opacity="0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,0,0,7"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>


                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="-7"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Post the full XAML and any code you have.

Comment: I did Edit the Question with more code